# How to display ForeignKey object in ListView - Django

Tags: django, listview, django-class-based-views

I have read up on this but I can't find something which solves my issue.

I am trying to display a table with a list of products with thumbnails.
The thumbnail field in the table returns no url, but returns a broken image link *only for the products which own a thumbnail.*

This list of products uses a ListView, and I can display the thumbnail fine in the detail view of the product (a DetailView) which uses the same template code

What do I need to do to display the thumbnail for each product in the ListView... ie. how must I change my queryset to pass the thumbnail into the template along with the product?

View

```
class ProductView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'product/product.html'
    context_object_name = 'product_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all()
```

Template

```
    {% for product in product_list %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/product/{{ product.id }}/">{{ product.title }}</a></td>
            <td>    {% if product.thumbnails.all %}
                    <img src="{{ product.thumbnail.url }}" alt="...">
                    {% endif %}
            </td>
            <td>{{ product.category }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.subcategory }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.status }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.date_added }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
```

Model

```
class ProductThumbnail(models.Model):   
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None, related_name='thumbnails')
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails/',
                          verbose_name='thumbnail', blank=True,)
```

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: What thumbnail you would like to show in the table if the Product has more than one thumbnail?

Comment: there is only one thumbnail per product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one thumbnail per Product, you should add the field

```
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='thumbnails/',
                      verbose_name='thumbnail', blank=True)
```

directly to the model `Product` and ditch the `ProductThumbnail` model. The way you designed your DB makes possible to have more thumbnails for each product (one-to-many relationship), but this makes your code needlessly complex.

If `thumbnail` was a field of the `Product` model, you could do simply:

```
{% if product.thumbnail %}
   <img src="{{ product.thumbnail.url }}" alt="...">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I cant get it to work if the thumbnail is part of the Product model, I just can't get the image to upload - in my view I save a product and some images with a formset. Thew images in the formset upload fine but the thumbnail image in the product form does not upload. Any idea what I may be missing?

Comment: Is the Product form defined with enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: Yes, and in my view product_form = AddEditProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES), check is_valid() and .save()

Comment: It is difficult to help you without viewing the complete code of form and view, you can have a look at [Django documentation on file upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/) to check if you are doing the right thing.

Comment: I appreciate the help! I'm not sure what I did but its working!

Answer (score 2):

`{% if product.thumbnails.all %}` should be `{% if product.thumbnail %}`

`{% if product.thumbnails.all %}` would only make sense if `product.thumbnails` was a reverse relation

EDIT: I misread the question

You need to loop through the thumbnails `{% for thumbnail in product.thumbnails.all %}`

Comment: With this code no broken image link is displayed, and no thumbnail.

Comment: product.thumbnails is a reverse relation, because ProductThumbnail has a ForeignKey to the model Product with related_name='thumbnails'

Comment: Apologies, I misread the question. Why is thumbnails a reverse_relation if each product only has 1?